# Error after installing react-native-elements package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I installed react-native-elements through npm a while ago. This morning, I was trying to create an Overlay component from the package, but for some reason I kept getting an error that no such component existed. So, foolishly, I ran `npm install react-native-elements` again, and now every time I try to build I get the following error:

`Unable to resolve ./social/SocialIcon" from "./C:\\Users\\L\\IdeaProjects\\FinalProject\\node_modules\\react-native-elements\\src\\index.js`: The module `./social/SocialIcon` could not be found"`.

I have react-native-vector-icons installed. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try install @expo/vector-icons

`npm install @expo/vector-icons --save`

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/620